# Break string Into multiple lines in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a string stored in SQL Server with multiple lines.

How I can select from SQL Server with multiline?

ForEx: data stored as `Line1 Line2 Line3`

How I can display

```
Line1 <nextLine>
Line2 <nextline>
Line3
```

Comment: Display **where??** In SQL Server Mgmt Studio?? In your own application??

Answer (score 0):

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fStringToTable(@P_KeyWordList AS Varchar(max),@Delimeter as varchar(1) )
RETURNS
@Result
TABLE(VarcharValue Varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @V_Keyword VARCHAR(255),
 @CIndex Int
 IF(@P_KeyWordList is not null)
 BEGIN
  SET @CIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@P_KeyWordList)
  WHILE (@CIndex > 0 )
  BEGIN
   SET @V_Keyword = SUBSTRING(@P_KeyWordList,1,@CIndex-1)
   SET @P_KeyWordList = SUBSTRING(@P_KeyWordList,@CIndex+1,LEN(@P_KeyWordList)-@CIndex)
   INSERT INTO @Result values (@V_Keyword)
   SET @CIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@P_KeyWordList)
  END
  SET @V_Keyword = @P_KeyWordList
  INSERT INTO @Result values (@V_Keyword)
 END
 RETURN
END
 GO
Select * from dbo.fStringToTable('l1 l2 l3',' ')